# Export option in shopp plugin

Tags: php, export, shopp

I am using shopp plugin for paypal in my wordpress site. In that there is an 'export options' in `shopp->orders` page.
The function for exporting the orders in the purchased page is

```
function exportcolumns () {
        $prefix = "p.";
        return array(
            $prefix.'id' => __('Line Item ID','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'optionlabel' => __('Product Variation Name','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'description' => __('Product Description','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'sku' => __('Product SKU','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'quantity' => __('Product Quantity Purchased','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'unitprice' => __('Product Unit Price','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'total' => __('Product Total Price','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'data' => __('Product Data','Shopp'),
            $prefix.'downloads' => __('Product Downloads','Shopp')
            );
    }
```

In this `$prefix.'optionlabel' => __('Product Variation Name','Shopp')`, contains the value `3482 Gouchh, Two Sems, With Insurance` in a single field. I have to separate it into 3 fields while exporting as xls.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are the three fields? This is a question on parsing, correct?

Comment: Another way would be to do the separation in your spreadsheet program. Most programs have data function that will allow you to split data from one column to multiple columns by 'separator' for instance 'comma'.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the best reason to export anything from Shopp is to move it to a different shopping cart platform.

I used Shopp for over a year on several sites, and it was never anything but a nightmare. It remained buggy, presented security problems. If you engage the logging you'll see that the code is SO SLOPPY that it constantly throws PHP errors.

EVERY update they did broke my sites and left me hemorrhaging money - while they jerked me around in their "support" area, delaying to extort money - and offering to repair the sites their junkware broke - for $500 EACH.

Strongly recommend getting away from Shopp.

Comment: I am a long term Shopp user and I know updates can break the site, but that is a risk with every theme, WP, plugin, update. As long as you do as instructed 'Create a backup of your files and database' there is not much harm done. The code throws 'PHP notices' from time to time (NOT PHP Errors). These notices don't stop the plugin from working correctly. There is no "We will repair your site for $500" service. With valid support you just contact the HD. If the problem is not theme or other plugin related they will help you out. And more often even if it is, they will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood your question, but if you have a string value that you want to extrapolate, [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is the function you need.

Assuming your product is stored in the $product variable

```
$export=explode(', ',$product['p.optionlabel']);
```

Will provide

```
array(3)
(
  [0] => string(11) "3482 Gouchh"
  [1] => string(8) "Two Sems"
  [2] => string(14) "With Insurance"
)
```

You can then use this to do your export.